# Can I install Kubuntu on a system having Lubuntu without affecting my files?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive, lubuntu, kubuntu

Sorry guys if the questions sounds a bit premitive. But i am very new to Ubuntu plus I dont have hat much knowledge about all these things related to computer.

Laptop: Dell Inspirion N5010
OS : Lubuntu (With just one partition)

Now the problem is, when I installed Lubuntu first to experience I forgot to make partitions of hard drive. So all my data is in the same partition as OS. Now I want to Install Kubuntu but I fear that if I install it then the whole partition (i.e whole hard disk basically) will be formatted. And I dont want to lose my data as it has my Educational Project data and some family pictures.

So, can I install ubuntu without losing my data? Please help soon.

Comment: Anyway, you should backup your data regularly. Really.

Answer (score 2):

Just keep your Lubuntu installation and add the KDE packages. No need for a second installation or anything else.

Be aware - all those thousand Ubuntu-distributions basically use just different default packages - thats all. Therefor if you want another desktop environment, install the related packages and that's it.

The following command should be enough

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

If that operation finished - logout and choose KDE on the login screen for the next login session.

This method has another advantage - you got 2 desktops available to compare them. If you finally do know which you want to use on the long term you can easily remove the other.